# How to filter for many tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, filtering

So far I have used the way showed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17003/stack-overflow-tag-filtering) to filter for tags I am interested in. I have a browser bookmark with an url like `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag1 or tag2 or tag3 or tag4 or ...`. This has worked fine so far.

However I noted today that not all of my tags show up any longer on the right side. Only something like the first 50 tags show up.

[Example link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%20or%20php%20or%20javascript%20or%20jquery%20or%20mysql%20or%20sql%20or%20xml%20or%20xslt%20or%20sql-server%20or%20ajax%20or%20mootools%20or%20regex%20or%20arrays%20or%20eclipse%20or%20json%20or%20soap%20or%20performance%20or%20html%20or%20query%20or%20spring%20or%20swing%20or%20git%20or%20svn%20or%20hibernate%20or%20eclipselink%20or%20security%20or%20oop%20or%20jsp%20or%20jsf%20or%20postgresql%20or%20mvc%20or%20mongodb%20or%20design-patterns%20or%20generics%20or%20servlets%20or%20caching%20or%20css3%20or%20tomcat%20or%20grails%20or%20jboss%20or%20groovy%20or%20jquery-mobile%20or%20jpa%20or%20spring-mvc%20or%20jdbc%20or%20ant%20or%20maven%20or%20solr%20or%20hadoop%20or%20flex%20or%20android) - the last tag in the url (`android`) is not shown on the right side and no questions tagged with `android` are included.

Maybe I am missing something and there is another/better way to filter for multiple tags?

Since it looks uncommon to have that many tags maybe my way of filtering through the questions is wrong. Is there an alternative? How are you filtering the questions you are interested in?

Comment: What in God's name are you doing with 50 tags?

Comment: See these links for some ideas: [link1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags), [link2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40117/add-advanced-search-option-to-search-within-a-users-interesting-favorite-ignore).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We only allow a certain level of crazy against the tag engine.  At this time you're a *severe* outlier compared to normal usage of the tags filters and were causing quite a few problems on the back-end not really designed for that usage model.  We may revisit this later, but for now we feel 50 is a sane cap for tag combinations.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. I updated the question with an example which I think would be not that uncommon. But maybe I am wrong :-(

Answer (score 3):

You can use wildcards (`*`) in your filters, use `tag*` instead of `tag1`, `tag2`, etc.

More information, about fitlering and wildcards, is provided in: [Please allow wildcards in tag searches](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/please-allow-wildcards-in-tag-searches/1726#1726)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this. But this isn't a real solution because many tags cannot be combined using a wildcard

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find any reference yet but I guess there is a limit to use `or` while searching a tag. And the limit should be 50. You can count that limit on [your given link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%20or%20php%20or%20javascript%20or%20jquery%20or%20mysql%20or%20sql%20or%20xml%20or%20xslt%20or%20sql-server%20or%20ajax%20or%20mootools%20or%20regex%20or%20arrays%20or%20eclipse%20or%20json%20or%20soap%20or%20performance%20or%20html%20or%20query%20or%20spring%20or%20swing%20or%20git%20or%20svn%20or%20hibernate%20or%20eclipselink%20or%20security%20or%20oop%20or%20jsp%20or%20jsf%20or%20postgresql%20or%20mvc%20or%20mongodb%20or%20design-patterns%20or%20generics%20or%20servlets%20or%20caching%20or%20css3%20or%20tomcat%20or%20grails%20or%20jboss%20or%20groovy%20or%20jquery-mobile%20or%20jpa%20or%20spring-mvc%20or%20jdbc%20or%20ant%20or%20maven%20or%20solr%20or%20hadoop%20or%20flex%20or%20android) where you have used 51 tags. [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+or+sql+or+sql-server+or+sql-server-2008+or+sqlite+or+tsql+or+sql-server-2005+or+postgresql+or+linq-to-sql+or+plsql+or+sqlite3+or+sql-server-2008-r2+or+nosql+or+mysqli+or+sqlalchemy+or+sql-server-ce+or+sql-server-2000+or+sql-order-by+or+sql-update+or+sql-injection+or+vb6+or+excel+or+excel-vba+or+excel-2007+or+excel-formula+or+export-to-excel+or+excel-2010+or+phpexcel+or+excel-2003+or+excel-interop+or+excel-addins+or+import-from-excel+or+jexcelapi+or+excel-dna+or+excel-vba-mac+or+linq-to-excel+or+excel-2011+or+excel-web-query+or+excelpackage+or+excel-2002+or+pyexcelerator+or+c+or+groovy+or+jquery-mobile+or+jpa+or+spring-mvc+or+jdbc+or+ant+or+maven+or+solr+or+hadoop+or+soap) here I added 52 tags but still it shows only first 50 tags.

[I found the reference.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161341/187824) :)

Comment: Yes it looks like there is a limit. But I am sure this limit wasn't there some days ago (thats why I tagged this post with `bug`). I have over 70 tags in this url with some of my prefered tags at the end. This worked fine so far. If a limit has been added there should be an alternative way to filter for >50 tags

Comment: @micha - Hmm.. Looks like they have restricted to 50. If so, they will update the FAQ soon.