# Does "intags:mine" no longer work above certain number of favorite/ignored tags?

Tags: support, search, tag-watching, ignored-tags, tag-search

Is there a limit on the number of tags after which searching using [intags:mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=intags%3Amine) no longer works?

On a local meta a user complained that [this search is not working for him](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27707/when-i-use-intagsmine-in-search-i-get-no-results). Since this user has many ignored tags, it was suggested in the comments that a limit on number of ignored tags might be a problem.

After he provided the list of his favorite and ignored tags, I have tried to use those tags to see whether I can replicate the problem. As I was adding the ignored tags, I found out that at a certain point the search indeed stopped working. (I have posted details, [as an answer on the local meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27707/when-i-use-intagsmine-in-search-i-get-no-results/27714#27714).) If I counted correctly, the search worked until there was 1023 ignored tags. Since this is quite close to a round number, this supports the suspicion that limit might be in play here. Still, it would be nice to have this confirmed officially, if it's indeed the case.

Comment: "[We only allow a certain level of crazy against the tag engine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161341)" (Nick Craver)